# How to detect if a double array (2D) has duplicates In Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

just trying to detect if a double array has in each row consecutive duplicates in it. Im not really sure why my code isnt working, any help will be highly appreciated

```
  For R As Integer = 0 To num - 1
        Dim RowClashes As Integer = 0
        For C1 As Integer = 0 To num - 2
            For C2 As Integer = C1 + 1 To num - 1
                If MyTeacherArray(R, C1) = MyTeacherArray(R, C2) Then
                    RowClashes += 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Period " & R & ":" & RowClashes)
    Next
```

Thanks

Comment: You should tag the question with the language you used for creating this code

Comment: is this really the case where we need to point out the difference between `==` and `=`? Note that operators depend on language, and without a language tag, it's practically impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks as if you would like to loop through all rows, and in each row check if there are more than one cell with a given value (i.e. two or more cells equal).

If this is correct, note that all three loops run up to the same limit, meaning `num - 1`. Is your table of the same number of rows and columns? If not, there you have one error.

Since you are not explaining why it **does not work**, I can't elaborate any further.

Comment: Hi, no there are not(rows and columns arent the same). rows are given by the user and colums are pre-set to 5.                                                      Dim MyTeacherArray(num, 5) As String                                                            The error im getting is an out of bounds error

Comment: In that case, re-check your code and see which of the loops are wrongly limited.

Comment: Re-reading your comment, you need to make the two inner loops going up to `5 - 1`.

Comment: Thanks will do now

Comment: If it still does not work, please explain what is wrong.

Comment: Still is giving me an error, :-- Index was outside bounds of the array

Comment: The question im trying to code is, make a double array, input into it and see if the are any clashes (im taking to be row duplicates) in the table.

Comment: I can see that there is an index problem by im honestly not sure how to correct it

Comment: Can you run it in debug mode? The error is telling you that when accessing your `MyTeacherArray(x, y)` either `x` or `y` has an illegal value. Run in debug mode an set a breakpoint at the `if` statement. Examine the values of the two indices, and see when you get the error (by the way, it is possible that you need to start from `1` and not `0`).

Comment: Will do that now, thanks so much for the help! really appreciated

Comment: My pleasure. I'm sure you will find the issue via the debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can just generate a string with all you array and convert it in md5.
After, you just have to compare md5 hashs.